# How was the voice acting done for Grand Moff Tarkin

Tags: production, star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, Disney/Lucasfilm had chosen to CGI the character of Grand Moff Tarkin. However the voice acting done for Tarkin sounded a lot like the original actor Peter Cushing. Did they just find someone else that sounded similar to Peter Cushing? Or was this special sound editing?

Comment: Might want some spoiler tags there.

Comment: @rickster we don't usually do spoilers here and the title is really hard to give specifics without spoiling anything. Feel free to edit a suggested change to something appropriate for the title. Maybe its ok to make the title more ambiguous?

Comment: One of those characters shows up early and throughout the film, so isn't much of a spoiler, but the other seem to be a special moment that's getting treated as spoiler-protection-worthy in other discussions. Proposed an edit to that effect.

Comment: I've taken that character reference out, it doesn't help the question anyway.

Comment: See also http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/65341/9391 for the same question about Princess Leia.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the filmmakers hired Guy Henry (he portrayed Minister of Magic Pius Thicknesse in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows) who has a superficial resemblance to Peter Cushing. He played the role of Tarkin and the VFX team then changed him into Cushing. In regards to his voice, the VFX sound team then probably added a simulation of Cushing’s voice with all the new dialogues.

References: [radiotimes.com](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2016-12-18/how-a-holby-city-actor-brought-one-of-star-wars-most-iconic-characters-back-to-life)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how the voice acting was done.

Answer (score 5):

According to the video below, a "source close to the film" confirmed that Guy Henry did provide the voice for Tarkin as well as the visual. I don't know how reliable that is and it also doesn't give any information about whether there was any post production sound editing done to make his voice sound any more like Peter Cushing's. Its not unreasonable to assume it was nothing more than some good quality voice acting, but I personally would like to know more details as I was wondering this same thing.

The particular section that mentions this starts at about the [2:50 mark](https://youtu.be/d-KJGLRmt0w?t=2m50s)

Answer (score 3):

The voice for Governor Tarkin was provided separately by Stephen Stanton. See [this article](http://movieweb.com/amp/rogue-one-star-wars-vfx-recreating-grand-moff-tarkin/).

Comment: I'm not sure that website got it right. Stephen Stanton provides [the voice of Tarkin](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0822812/) in __[Star Wars Rebels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2930604/)__, but when he [tweeted](https://twitter.com/Stephen_Stanton/status/806681494357823488) about "Rogue One" he said he is voicing __Admiral Raddus__.

Comment: Interesting! I was assuming the site had valid info, but it could we have been incorrect.