# Was Carrie Fisher's voice used in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, voice-acting

In *Rogue One*, Princess Leia has a single line. Was it voiced by Carrie Fisher or another voice actress?

[image: Princess Leia]

---

Edit: To clarify, was it 1977 Carrie Fisher, 2016 Carrie Fisher, or someone else?

Comment: Related: [How was the voice acting done for Grand Moff Tarkin](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65206/how-was-the-voice-acting-done-for-grand-moff-tarkin/65260#65260)

Comment: Anecdotally, I have read that the line Leia says in *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story* - "Hope" - was taken from a line in *Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope*. I don't have any proof of that, however.

Comment: The __[Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Leia_Organa#Rogue_One)__ says: _"She is __portrayed by Ingvild Deila__ with a computer-generated face of a younger Carrie Fisher and __archive footage of Carrie Fisher's voice__."_  But no source is given for that info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**YES**

According to [this interview with *Rogue One* sound editors](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/rogue-one-sound-editors-reveal-how-they-found-princess-leias-hope-and-more-production-secrets-132116513.html) **Matthew Wood** and **Christopher Scarabosio**, it's an old recording of Fisher:

> **Gwynne Watkins (Yahoo Movies)**: Carrie Fisher, who died suddenly last month, has obviously been on
>   Star Wars fans’ minds. What was your role in creating the Princess
>   Leia scene at the very end?
>
> **Matthew Wood**: First off, we kind of knew what the script was going to be for
>   that final line, how they wanted to put the button on the whole movie
>   and then connect it right up to New Hope. So **I got a call to try to
>   find the original tapes of anything that Carrie had done from ’77. I
>   found the original quarter-inch rolls in an archives box at Lucasfilm,
>   and I just transferred every single take of the “Help me, Obi-Wan
>   Kenobi, you’re my only hope” scene, the hologram scene from the
>   original film. And there were a lot of takes. So I grabbed all that.**
>
> The machine that it was played back on doesn’t really exist that much
>   anymore, so I was able to grab the special heads for that and transfer
>   it into Pro Tools and just go through [the takes]. And **John Gilroy, who’s the picture editor on the film, and
>   John Swartz, the producer, found a take that they thought really
>   worked for that. So it is an original line from Carrie in 1977.**
>   [Producer and effects supervisor] John Knoll’s department had the main
>   challenge of making that scene work visually, and I know that he
>   mentioned that **Carrie had seen almost the final project of what we had
>   done there and actually liked it.**

Comment: In a similar fashion, they used a take of Alex Guiness saying "afraid" in A New Hope, cut out the "rai", and used it in The Force Awakens during the scene where Rey finds the lightsaber.

Answer (score 19):

Princess Leia was portrayed and voiced by Norwegian actress Ingvild Deila. They used archival footage to make character look and sound like Carrie Fisher.

[image]

Image Courtesy: [Movie Pilot](https://images.moviepilot.com/images/c_limit,q_auto,w_710/l8shku7vomr8vdbtowou/ingvild-deila-left-carrie-fisher-right-both-played-leia.jpg)

As per [this source](http://moviepilot.com/p/princess-leia-actress-ingvild-deila/4173072),

> While Deila initially acted in the scene, later in post-production the team from Light and Magic, Lucasfilm's in-house visual effects company, later **used archival footage to alter Deila's looks and voice to more accurately match Fisher's**. The use of a body double meant that Leia's movements and features looked life-like and convincing.

Comment: So the voice is from archive footage? The original voice of Carrie Fisher from the original Star Wars, 40 years ago?

Comment: They used archive footage to alter Deila's looks and voice to more accurately match Fisher's.

Comment: The cited article is from a fan blog (see their [About Us](https://moviepilot.com/creators) page).  Is there a more authoritative source for the claim about altering Deila's voice?  Maybe an interview with or press release from the filmmakers?

Comment: @Psychonaut Well, I did google around, but couldn't find any words from filmmakers. I posted a tweet from the actress herself in previous answer. IMDb also credited her as Leia. She had to keep it secret until release. Perhaps this is the reason there aren't any words from filmmakers.

Comment: @AJ So perhaps the matter of how Leia was voiced is, at this point, really just unverified speculation.

Comment: Here's a 7 minute interview with the actress, yet not a peep about who did the voice: http://io9.gizmodo.com/meet-the-actress-who-had-to-don-princess-leias-buns-in-1793257284

Comment: @BCdotWEB Even she said that in her tweets. You can see that in deleted answer, but she doesn't claim that it was her voice.

Comment: They didn't "alter" anything.  They completely replaced her face with Fisher's, and used Carrie Fisher's voice.  The only word spoken by Leia in Rogue One is "Hope".  That word was taken from the audio in the original Star Wars when Leia says "Help us Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're our only **hope**".

Comment: @Tim Well, that's what I mentioned in the last paragraph.